# What's the faster Java REST Service Framework?

Tags: java, android, tomcat, jersey, restlet

I'm building a Java Rest Webservice to send lots of data, specifically objects serialized in XML using SimpleXML. I'm using:

- Server side: Tomcat  + Jersey
- Client side: Android + Restlet for Android

The performance obtained is worse than I expected. XML Serialization/Deserialization seems that isn't the problem. I think that it is in the server side but I don't know if it's Tomcat or Jersey.

Are there better options available?

Thanks

Comment: What does your profiling information show?

Comment: As Jon Skeet asked, you should find out if low performance is caused by XML parsing or connection speed ...

Comment: I calculated the serialization deserialization time and it's a low part of the total time.

Comment: well the quick suggestion would be REST

Comment: Yes, it's REST, Jersey is a RestFul framework and I'm asking if exists better options

Answer (score 1):

You could attempt to use Jetty rather than Tomcat.  But more likely you need to tweak the configuration settings on Tomcat to match your load.  Are you sending lots of small requests or a few big ones?

You should also look for concurrency issues; do you have a small number of objects which are accessed by lots of requests?  And how much time does the business logic take?

One way of testing is to have a very simple 'ping' resource in Jersey which provides a simple text response; no other processing.  That should give you an idea of the best possible performance, and you can work backwards from that to find out what is slowing things down.

One other thing: put some metrics in place so that you can record how long various method calls take.  The Metrics package for Java from Coda Hale is a good way to go here.

Comment: I have another application with a soap webservice build with RemObjects Software and the client side using Android with KSoap and the performance is better. I expected that a RESTFul Webservice was ligher and faster than a Soap Webservice

Comment: Updated my answer with some more questions and also pointers.

Comment: I usually send small requests except the initialization that do big requests. The business logic isn't the problem because I have a log that shows that this part is fast. That includes business, database access and serialization/deserialization of objects. I will try that Metrics packages. Thanks

Comment: I would suggest that you build a 'ping' resource and time it, then go play with some of the configuration options in Tomcat to see if you can get the performance up.  Or swap Tomcat out for Jetty and do the same thing.  To give you some idea, a ping resource on a Jetty/Jersey stack on decent hardware should handle multiple thousands of requests per second.

Answer (score 1):

[RESTDroid](https://github.com/PCreations/RESTDroid/) is a library which let's you easily implement a REST client for android. I think it should probably fits your need :) It's an easy library, if you're searching for something more powerful (but more complicated) take a look to [RoboSpice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice)